# How to handle backup scenario in spark-structured streaming using joins?

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark-sql 2.4.1 , spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.4.1.jar and java8. I have scenario , where I need join streaming data with C*/Cassandra table data.

I have two tables as below "**master_table**" & "**backup_table**"

```
table kspace.master_table(
    statement_id int,
    statement_flag text,
    statement_date date,
    x_val double,
    y_val double,
    z_val double,
    PRIMARY KEY (( statement_id ), statement_date)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY ( statement_date DESC );

table kspace.backup_table(
    statement_id int,
    statement_flag text,
    statement_date date,
    x_val double,
    y_val double,
    z_val double,
    backup_timestamp timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY ((statement_id ), statement_date, backup_timestamp )
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY ( statement_date DESC,   backup_timestamp DESC);
```

Each streaming record would have "statement_flag" which might be "I" or "U".

1. If record with "I" comes we directly insert into "master_table".
2. If record with "U" comes , we need to check if there is any record for given ( statement_id ), statement_date in "master_table".
3. If there is record in "master_table" copy that one to "backup_table" with current timestamp i.e. backup_timestamp.
4. Update the record in "master_table" with latest record.

The following code is supposed to do it, but it's not.

```
Dataset<Row> baseDs = //streaming data from topic
Dataset<Row> i_records = baseDs.filter(col("statement_flag").equalTo("I"));
Dataset<Row> u_records = baseDs.filter(col("statement_flag").equalTo("U"));

String keyspace="kspace";
String master_table = "master_table";
String backup_table = "backup_table";

Dataset<Row> cassandraMasterTableDs = getCassandraTableData(sparkSession, keyspace , master_table);

writeDfToCassandra(baseDs.toDF(), keyspace, master_table);

u_records.createOrReplaceTempView("u_records");
cassandraMasterTableDs.createOrReplaceTempView("persisted_records");

Dataset<Row> joinUpdatedRecordsDs =  sparkSession.sql(
            " select p.statement_id, p.statement_flag, p.statement_date,"
            + "p.x_val,p.y_val,p.z_val "
            + " from persisted_records as p "
            + "join u_records as u "
            + "on p.statement_id = u.statement_id  and p.statement_date = u.statement_date");

Dataset<Row> updated_records = joinUpdatedRecordsDs
  .withColumn("backup_timestamp", current_timestamp());

writeDfToCassandra(updated_records.toDF(), keyspace, backup_table);
```

Every thing from "master_table" is copied to backup_table. In fact it suppose to copy only previous version of records not latest.

Suppose to copy only previous version of records from master_table but everything been copied to backup_table

How to make only previous version of records from `master_table` only copied to `backup_table` not latest one?

### Sample Data

For first record with "I" flag

master_table

[image]

backup_table

[image]

For the second record with "U" flag, i.e. same as earlier except "y_val" column data.

master_table

[image]

backup_table

Expected

[image]

But actual table data is

[image]